# How can I bypass this Powershell warning message?

Tags: excel, powershell

I have always used this script to open an Excel workbook automatically, save it and use it. Since the workbook has been modified the script does not work, because every time I open the file a popup appears that warns me that there are errors inside the workbook.

How can I bypass this problem and make Powershell press the "ok" button in the warning message to continue with the update?

[image]

```
$file = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\SPC_Analysis_v2.3 - 36 mesi_250_macchine_IPC - Copia - Copia.xlsm' 
$x1 = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$x1.Visible = $false                
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yy HH-mm-ss")  
$filename = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\SPC\IPC\IPC_QCP - Copia ' + $enddate + '.xlsm' 
$wb = $x1.workbooks.Open($file) 
$wb.RefreshAll() 
$wb.SaveAs($filename) 
$wb.Close() 
$x1.Quit() 
Remove-Variable wb,x1
```

Comment: *a popup appears that warns me that there are errors inside the workbook* Whay about fixing those errors? No Joke. Anyways, in VBA there is a method called `DisplayAlerts` to turn off alerts (make sure you turn them on after you are done!), but don't know how to invoke it on your script. maybe something like `$x1.DisplayAlerts=$False` and `$x1.DisplayAlerts=$True`? Check https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d963956a-02c4-488f-b59c-bb730b1506b0/displayalerts-false-is-not-working?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Thank you, it works , very grateful

Comment: Great! I've posted as an answer then so you can accept it as valid :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off alerts using:

`$x1.DisplayAlerts=$False`

This will turn off all alerts on Excel (except critical errors). Because it turns off all alerts, make sure you turn them on after you are done!

`$x1.DisplayAlerts=$True`

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d963956a-02c4-488f-b59c-bb730b1506b0/displayalerts-false-is-not-working?forum=winserverpowershell

Info about property DisplayAlerts:

> [DisplayAlerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts)